# Add custom property to Android buildTypes gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Is it possible to add an custom property to Android buildTypes in the build.gradle? I would like to use this property in an other task.

```
    android {
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                myProp 'aaa'
            }
            alpha {
                versionNameSuffix '-ALPHA'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                myProp 'bbb'
            }
            beta {
                versionNameSuffix '-BETA'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                myProp 'ccc'
            }
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                myProp 'dddd'
            }
       }

       buildTypes.each { buildType ->
          def myTool = task("${buildType.name}MyTool", type: Exec) {
               commandLine 'python', "myTool.py", '-b', buildType.myProp
          }
          preBuild.dependsOn myTool 
       }
    }
```

Comment: have a look at this post
http://www.rainbowbreeze.it/environmental-variables-api-key-and-secret-buildconfig-and-android-studio/
you can define a constant in your generated BuildConfig.java

Comment: I don't want to have this property in my buildConfig, I only want to use this property in my gradle file